# How do I run Multiple scripts on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have written a few Jmeter scripts *.jmx and need to run these as a scenario with 50% users on one and the rest on the other scripts with max 200 Threads (VUsers). Can this be done on Jmeter? or do i need Blazemeter ?please help ? Thanks in advance. Rick

Comment: you can combine scripts into one jmx script with multiple threadgroups with user defined loads and start all in parallel or this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter/26954448#26954448

Answer (score 0):

For this test, you would have two thread groups running consecutively.

Both thread groups have 100 users each (50%)

First thread group runs first scenario, the other one runs all the other scenarios. If you need the scenarios all running at the same time, you can add more thread groups, and split the users down further.