# How to run multiple .jmx recorded script at one instance on non-gui mode without Maven?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am doing Performance testing for my web App with JMeter.

I tried running 6 .jmx by merging all 6 scripts in one .JMX script(through JMeter GUI mode) after that executed on command prompt it was saying active threads are 6(initially), but when i get report after executing .jtl(get after executing .jmx) and tried to check number of active thread it was saying only 1 thread was active through out the time.Here are the 2 Snapshots:
[image: Command prompt execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yrhn.jpg)

[image]

So is it possible to run multiple .jmx recorded script which have different different credentials to login into web App and executing different tasks and also I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter) and given answer by Dmitri & Nachiket.

I also tried to run more than 1 .jmx scripts one time on command prompt like :

**>jmeter -n -t "D:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\P_testing170817_U_rama.jmx" "D:\Program Files\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\P_testing170817_U_superuser.jmx**

Comment: Could you explain how you merge those 6 scripts into one? Does your result have 6 different Thread groups? 

I suppose each *.jmx file contains 1 Thread Group.

Comment: Yes [Klinggac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635802/klingac), i have 6 different Thread groups(i.e. each .jmx file contains only one Thread Group) and i merged these .jmx files using merge option on Jmeter on File Menu(as was suggested on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter)). You can see here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0IS7TX6_qqSk1mSHlnQUhmZVU/view?usp=sharing  and 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx0IS7TX6_qqVnlmMUV4SkpBVTg/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing property in jmeter.properties which count threads:

> By default, JMeter do not save threads count in JTL files. If you plan
>   to work with JMeter JTL files, you should enable it by uncommenting in
>   JMETER-INSTALL-DIR/bin/jmeter.properties the line:

```
 jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
```