# How to run jmeter jmx files parallely from single command prompt

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have 5 different jmx files in my project. I need to do performance testing by running all these jmx files parallely. Currently i'm opening 5 different jmeter command prompt instance and triggering the execution.
Is there any way i can execute all these jmx files from 1 jmeter command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your operating system the options are in:

- Linux: there is a [`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command, you can go for something like:

  ```
  parallel --gnu << 'EOF'
  jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
  jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result2.jtl
  etc.
  EOF
  ```
- Windows: you can create a batch script assuming [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command something like:

  ```
  start jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
  start jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl
  etc.
  ```

As a cross-platform unified solution you can consider using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter script you can kick off multiple JMeter tests in parallel using simple declarative YAML syntax like:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    script: test1.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: test2.jmx
- scenario: 
    script: test3.jmx
    #etc
```

See [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some other tools like Ant or Maven or jenkins for that.

Please check the below link for more information:-

**[How to run multiple jmx scripts together in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter)**

Answer (score 0):

Praveen, I don't think this is currently possible in JMeter to execute multiple .jmx files from single command , but I would suggest adding all 5 scripts in a single .jmx file if possible in your scenario.