# How to run two .jmx files together in JMeter and create one report for both files?

Tags: cmd, jmeter, load-testing, jmx

How to run two .jmx files together in JMeter and create one report for both files.

I know we can run two .jmx scripts by using the below-listed command in JMeter,

=> **Jmeter.bat or Jmeter.sh -n -t scritp1.jmx & Jmeter.bat or Jmeter.sh -n -t scritp2.jmx .**

But how to create one shell script for both .jmx file and make one report.

Here is my requirement :

- I am having a requirement for running 1000 users and need to run 500 - 500 users twice from two scrips. Also, I am using just two users and ran it multiples times to reach 500 requests.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

1. On Windows you can use start command, i.e. create a [batch file](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-windows-batch-script/) looking like:

   ```
   start jmeter -n -t test1.jmx -l result1.jtl
   start jmeter -n -t test2.jmx -l result2.jtl
   ```

   when the scripts finish you can combine the .jtl files using [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)
2. On Linux and other Unix-like operating systems you can use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) like:

   ```
   parallel jmeter -n -t test{}.jmx -r -l result{}.jtl ::: 1 2
   ```
3. It might be easier to use [Taurus tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests/) as a wrapper, this way you won't have to merge results manually after the run, the relevant [Taurus YAML configuration file](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) would be something like:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
   - scenario:
       script: test1.jmx
   - scenario: 
       script: test2.jmx
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Merge the result files with the plugin https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/